# How do I append a page's URL to a social media 'sharing' URL in jQuery?

Tags: javascript

How do I create a link that takes the static part of a 'sharing' link (of a social media site like LinkedIn) and appends the url of the current page? So that a user can share the page's URL on their social media account.

I do not want to use Share This or any other such widgets.

Thanks

**EDIT**

So of the solutions suggested I opted for the jQuery one. After a lot of help, this was the solution:

HTML

```
<a class="linkedin" href="#">LinkedIn</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('a.linkedin').click(function() {
    var link = document.location;
    var url = "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=" + link;
    document.location.href = url;
  });
});
```

Obviously, it can work for any social media site that allows such URLs.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple link instead of a span + js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not mind using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('a#link').click(function() {
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        var url = "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=" + link;
        document.location.href=url;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is assuming he's using JQuery

Comment: That is exactly what my post says "If you do not mind using jQuery"

Comment: Using jQ for something this simple and nothing else is heinous. Always consider the actual cost/benefit to loading jQ or just using pure JS in simple situations.

Comment: I agree, but I just put this here for reference if anyone is using jQuery anyway, which a large majority does

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained my question very well. The HTML in your jsfiddle gives text.com as the link. I need the link to be the current page, which could be any url on my site. So the url parameter in your jsfiddle would be: url=http://jsfiddle.net/2rfwg/. Any ideas how I can acheive this?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2rfwg/3/ Note that the url returned now is different from the one it is viewing but I think this is due to the internals of jsfiddle.net Please check if this works in your own site

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedIn has docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-linkedin) on this and what parameters their url expects. I left out the `summary` param.

JS 101 : You're looking for the window.open method. See [docs for this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open). All you have to do is **(1)** write a function that opens a window with the url. **(2)** Call this function in the [onclick event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick) of the a element.

With just pure javascript, It should look something like this:

```
<script>
    function shareOnLinked(url, title, summary)
    {
     window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+ 
           url +'&title='+title+'&summary='+summary);
    }
</script>
<a href='#' 
   onclick='shareOnLinked("http://stackoverflow.com",
                                   "Great QandA","SomeSummary");'> 
Share On Linked in</a>
```

See live example : http://jsfiddle.net/PpC5S/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use (Pure Javascript without any lib's)

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=" onclick='function(j){ window.location = j.href + window.location }(this)'>
```